# Datetime value not showing properly in jQuery data table

Tags: javascript, c#, datatables

I want to get the timestamp in data table . how to format my datetime in the jquery datatable function?

sql server datatime data, how to edit the columns so that i cant get the proper datetime in the data time. i have tried with type: 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy', but its not working

```
 2018-11-23 07:49:35.073
     data type - date time
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                            $('#myTable').DataTable({
                                "ajax": {
                                    "url": "/Temperature/loaddata",
                                    "type": "GET",
                                    "datatype": "json"
                                },
                                "columns": [
                                        { "data": "id", "autoWidth": true },
                                        { "data": "updatedDate", "autoWidth": true, type: 'date-dd-mmm-yyyy', targets: 0 },
                                        { "data": "deviceid", "autoWidth": true },
                                        { "data": "devicename", "autoWidth": true },
                                        { "data": "temp", "autoWidth": true },
                                        { "data": "faht", "autoWidth": true }
                                ]
                            });
                        });
```

c# code

```
public  ActionResult loaddata()
{ 
    using (smartpondEntities dc = new smartpondEntities())
    {
        var data = dc.Temperatures.OrderBy(a => a.id).ToList();
        return Json(new { data = data}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

json sample data

```
[{"id":1,"updatedDate":"2018-11-23T07:49:35.073","DeviceTime":null,"deviceid":1,"devicename":"aaaa","temp":28.50,"faht":87.90},{"id":2,"updatedDate":"2018-11-23T07:49:42.1","DeviceTime":null,"deviceid":1,"devicename":"aaaa","temp":28.50,"faht":87.90}]
```

output

```
/Date(1542939575073)/
```

exp op

```
23 Nov 2018 13:10:10
```

Comment: Date is fine. It's just a matter of formatting to string. You need to format your date to expected when you displaying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) for datetimes ([docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)). so in your render:

```
{
    title: "Date",// name 
    render: function (data, type, row) {//data
        return moment(row.updatedDate).format('DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a render function to format/customize your data

For Ex:

```
"columns": [
{ "data": "engine" },
{ "data": "browser" },
{
  "data": "platform",
  "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
               return ConvertToDate(data);
            }
}
```

Convert your date in ConvertToDate(data) function.

```
function ConvertToDate(data){
     return data;//Converted date
}
```

Comment: error saying - "ConvertToDate is not defined", do i need to make a another function

Comment: you need to add a function named ConvertToDate(date)

Answer (score 0):

**To render date format in Angular-Datatables, first you need to install npm moment**

> npm install moment --save

```
import * as moment from 'moment'; // import moment wherein you are using in component

{
  title: 'CreatedAt',
  data: 'CreatedAt',
  render: (data:any,type:any,full:any)=>{
    return moment(data).format('L'); 
// more related moment format you can check here - https://momentjs.com
   }
}
```