# Datetime value not showing in jQuery data table

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to display some data in a datatable but Datetime in this case RegisterDate value not showing properly in jQuery data table. My Project is Asp.Net MVC. It shows as /Date(1542939575073)/
I do not know how to format my datetime in the jquery datatable function. Please help.
Here is my code in my Index View ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {


            $("#myTable").DataTable({

                "processing": true,  
                "serverSide": true,  
                "filter": false,  
                "orderMulti": false,  
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Home/LoadEmployees",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "json" 
                },
                "columns": [ 
                    { "data": "IdCardNr", "name": "IdCardNr", "autoWidth": true }, 
                    { "data": "RegisterDate","name": "RegisterDate", "autoWidth": true },
                    { "data": "PhonerNr", "name": "PhonreNr", "autoWidth": true },

                ] 
            });

        });
```

I know I must have  kind of  render some where inside but I do not know how to create it and where exactly to put it even if it should be right after "data" : "RegisterDate"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Datetime value not showing properly in jQuery data table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53447383/datetime-value-not-showing-properly-in-jquery-data-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code after "data": RegidterDate

```
 "render": function (mydata) {
                                var date = new Date(parseInt(mydata.substr(6)));
                                var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
                                return date.getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + date.getFullYear();
```